# Filtering list based on custom data

Tags: java

I have a class `Accumulation` like below

```
public class Accumulation implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String mobileNo;
  private String address;
  private int count;

  --
  getter
  setter
}
```

I get data from my repository by

```
List<Accumulation> accumulations = repository.getAccumulation();
```

Now for Example  `List<Accumulation>` accumulations contains 5 records.

```
First records : 123, Test1, 2
Second records : 123, Test1, 2
Third records : 123, Test1, 2
Fourth records : 123, Test1, 1
Fifth records : 123, Test1, 2
```

We can get total count by below code.

```
   int totalCount = accumulations.stream().mapToInt(Accumulation::getCount).sum();
```

So from above list we can get total count is :: 9

what I want : I want to get only 8 count records.

For example : from the 5 records if we get only 4 records (First, Second, Third, Fifth) then we can get 8 count.

How to achieve the above logic? I am not able find any thing.

Comment: are you trying to get sublist of elements that makes the count 8 ? (if I understand properly). You should clearly address it.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Correct

Comment: what is your goal? get a list without last element or get a list based on specified records count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting the list to be short, you can just brute-force search all combinations of accumulations.  The following snippet makes use of `BitSet` class to avoid doing manual bitmask manipulation:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

Optional<List<Accumulation>> result = LongStream.range(0, 1L << accumulations.size())
    .mapToObj(bits -> BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {bits}))
    .filter(bits -> 8 == bits.stream()
            .map(i -> accumulations.get(i).getCount())
            .sum()
    )
    .map(bits -> bits.stream()
            .mapToObj(accumulations::get)
            .collect(toList())
    )
    .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a sub of the returning list you can use [List.subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)

For getting 8 elements:

```
ListItems.subList(0, 8);
```

Comment: I think he didnt ask for 8 element. he asked for sub list of element that makes the count 8. so this is not the correct answer

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Correct